# Заблокировали приложение. Стоит ли попробовать повысить возрастное ограничение?

Tags: android, google-play

Здравствуйте. Заблокировали приложение по причине нарушения политики насилия. Приложение новостное. При публикации это указывалось. Возрастное ограничение Е10.
причина блокировки в скриншоте [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сообщении о блокировке, было указано что я могу пересмотреть политику насилия, и перезалить его под другим package name. Что именно я должен пересмотреть. Фильтрацию самих картинок,но по какому кретитерию. Или просто попробовать повысить возрастное ограничению? Или может не стоит рисковать аккаунтом в вообще забить на данное приложение...

Comment: Ну да, если у вас допустимы картинки и тексты про насилие, то надо повышать возрастное ограничение

Comment: Ясно. Буду пробовать. Спасибо